# Is there a way to hide the compile error messages in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I just don't want to see these annoying error messages in red, the wavy error line is fine.

[image: See this image for reference]

Comment: What extensions do you have active? This isn't from rust-analyzer. It's probably from something like the "Error Lens" extension.

Answer (score 3):

This is **Error lens** extension if I'm not mistaken.

If you want to disable **warnning messages** and only show **error messages**, you can do as follows:

1. First press `F1` (or `Ctr + Shift + p`) to search all commands;
2. Paste and search `preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`;
3. Then you'll see a json file opens up, and you can customize pretty much everything, include extensions;
4. Adding such:

```
"errorLens.enabledDiagnosticLevels": ["error"],
```

This tells **Error lens** extension only show inline error messages. Other options are "hint", "info", "warning".